# Infinite Scroll and DFP

Tags: loop, infinite-scroll

Well , I'm trying the next loop to make work DFP in an Infinite Scroll.

I thought that if I change the name of the Slot I could get the banner shown, so I tried this:

```
<!-- DFP Controller -->
  <script>
   <?php if(is_home()) : ?>
   googletag.cmd.push(function() {
     gptadslots[0]= googletag.defineSlot('/94102516/home_960x90_a', [[960,90]],'960x90_a').addService(googletag.pubads());
     gptadslots[1]= googletag.defineSlot('/94102516/home_300x250', [[300,250]],'300x250').addService(googletag.pubads());
     gptadslots[2]= googletag.defineSlot('/94102516/home_960x90_b', [[960,90]],'960x90_b').addService(googletag.pubads());
     gptadslots[3]= googletag.defineSlot('/94102516/home_960x90_c', [[960,90]],'960x90_c').addService(googletag.pubads());

     googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
     googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
     googletag.pubads().enableAsyncRendering();
     googletag.enableServices();
   });
 <?php elseif(is_category()) : ?>
 googletag.cmd.push(function() {

   gptadslots[0]= googletag.defineSlot('/94102516/<?php adCat(); ?>_960x90', [[960,90]],'960x90').addService(googletag.pubads());
   gptadslots[1]= googletag.defineSlot('/94102516/<?php adCat(); ?>_300x250', [[300,250]],'300x250').addService(googletag.pubads());

   googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
   googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
   googletag.pubads().enableAsyncRendering();
   googletag.enableServices();
 });

<?php elseif(is_single()) : ?>
 googletag.cmd.push(function() {

  gptadslots[0]= googletag.defineSlot('/9410/<?php adCat(); ?>_960x90', [[960,90]],'960x90').addService(googletag.pubads());
  gptadslots[1]= googletag.defineSlot('/9410/<?php adCat(); ?>_300x250', [[300,250]],'300x250').addService(googletag.pubads());
  // gptadslots[2]= googletag.defineSlot('/94102516/notas_300x600', [[300,600]],'300x600n').addService(googletag.pubads());

  googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
  googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
  googletag.pubads().enableAsyncRendering();
  googletag.enableServices();
});
<?php endif; ?>

</script>
<!-- End DFP Controller -->
```

And , in the loop I'm trying this:

```
<section class="sixth">
  <?php
       //--- Sixth Featured
  $featured_6 = array(
   'posts_per_page' => 3,
   'offset' => 7
   );

  $f6 = new WP_Query( $featured_6 );

  if (  $f6->have_posts() ) :
    $count = 0;
  while (  $f6->have_posts() ) :  $f6->the_post();
  $count++;
  if ($count == 2) :
    ?>

  <article data-number="<?php echo $count; ?>">
    <!-- /941025/home_300x250_<?php echo $count; ?> -->
    <figure id="300x250_<?php echo $count; ?>" class="iHolder lazyload" style="width:300px;">
      <script>
       googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        googletag.display('300x250');    
      });
    </script>
  </figure>
</article>

<?php else : ?>

  <article>
    <figure class="iHolder">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail("dreams-1200x800", array( 'class'  => "lazyload"));?>
      </a>
    </figure>

    <div class="desc" style="background:#13254b;">
      <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    </div>
  </article>

  <?php
  endif;
  endwhile;
  endif;
  ?>
```

But, the thing is that is not working , obviously because the call is not getting the loop $counter, anyone , have a better idea??

thank you